# Sum Comma Separated string in a column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query as below:

```
WITH mytable as
(
    SELECT 
        (CAST(CASE 
                 WHEN Quote_Value LIKE '-%' THEN N'0' 
                 WHEN Quote_Value = '' THEN N'0' 
                 ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(Quote_Value,'$',''),',','+') 
              END as Decimal)) as q,
        DATEDIFF(week, '2015-10-06', date) AS WeekNumber
    FROM 
        Showroom_perf)  
SELECT
    WeekNumber,
    SUM(q) as [Quote Value]
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    WeekNumber
```

Where the `Quote_Value` can have some coma separated values as well - if yes then the coma separated values need to be summed.

Can anybody suggest if I can do it without any function and/or table created ?
A possible solution I see is executing a expression as bellow :

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '23,12,12,32,43';
set @str = 'select '+replace(@str, ',', '+');
exec(@str);
```

But not sure if this can be executed inside my query. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with CTE?

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '23|12|12|32|43';
declare @delimiter nvarchar(1) = '|';

;WITH SplitTable AS
(
    SELECT
        LEFT(@str,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str)-1) AS Part
            ,RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@str)) AS Remainder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,Remainder)-1)
            ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@delimiter,Remainder))
        FROM SplitTable
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@delimiter,Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Remainder,null
        FROM SplitTable
        WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@delimiter,Remainder)=0
)
SELECT sum(convert(int,Part)) FROM SplitTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a work around that is working for me now - but just want to know if this is the right way or if it has any other impact:

```
WITH mytable as(
SELECT 
    (CAST(CASE  WHEN Quote_Value LIKE '-%' THEN N'0' WHEN Quote_Value = '' THEN N'0' 
    ELSE CAST('<root><e>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Quote_Value,'$',''),',','+') + '</e></root>' AS XML)
        .value('sum(/root/e) + count(/root/e) * 10', 'Decimal') END as Decimal)) as q,
    DATEDIFF(week, '2015-10-06', date) AS WeekNumber
    FROM Showroom_perf
)  
Select 
WeekNumber,
SUM(q) as [Quote Value]
from mytable
GROUP BY
WeekNumber
```